# How to unit test exceptions from ReactiveCommand (ReactiveUI)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, reactiveui

I'm using xUnit and ReactiveUI  11.2 (for WPF, .NET Framework 4.8, but I think my question is more generic).

Basically, I want to test my `ReactiveCommand` in the ViewModels.

For instance, there was some condition that threw an exception in my code, and my program crashes.

I want to make a unit test to reproduce this error (the unit test should fail), then I'll fix my bug, prevent somehow the exception, and then my test should pass to reflect the fix. (pretty standard procedure).

The problem is, any exception thrown during a ReactiveCommand seem to be "swallowed" by ReactiveUI, **the exception does not make the test fail**.

Also, the same happens if I try to write `Assert()` statements in the callback of `.Subscribe()` : I can see during debug that my assertion fail properly, but the test is marked in green as "passed" anyway.

I tried different way by playing a bit with the schedulers, doesn't improve anything.
I tried to use ".ThrownExceptions" as described doesn't help either.

Some documentation here : https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/testing/

---

## TL;DR

How can I make exceptions in my `ReactiveCommand`s cause my unit tests to fail ? How am I supposed to unit tests `ReactiveCommand`s entirely ?

---

Below is a complete program that demonstrate the issue.

Use with NuGet packages :
xunit 2.4.1, 
xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.1, 
ReactiveUI.Testing 11.2.1

```
using Microsoft.Reactive.Testing;
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.Testing;
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using Xunit;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Foo
    {

        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> TestCommand { get; }

        public Foo(IScheduler? scheduler = null)
        {
            scheduler ??= RxApp.MainThreadScheduler;

            TestCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(Explode, canExecute: null, outputScheduler: scheduler);
        }

        public void Explode()
        {
            throw new Exception("Boom");
        }
    }

    public class ReactiveCommandTests
    {

        // Should fail? (it doesn't fail)
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            foo.TestCommand.Execute().Subscribe();
        }

        // Should fail (it fails alright ! no ReactiveUI Observable here...)
        [Fact]
        public void Test2()
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            foo.Explode();
        }

        // Should fail? (it doesn't fail)
        [Fact]
        public void Test3()
        {
            var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
            var foo = new Foo(testScheduler);
            foo.TestCommand.Execute().Subscribe();
        }

        // Should fail? (it doesn't fail)
        [Fact]
        public void Test4()
        {
            new TestScheduler().With(scheduler =>
            {
                var foo = new Foo(scheduler);
                foo.TestCommand.Execute().Subscribe();

            });
        }

        // Should fail ? (it doesn't fail)
        [Fact]
        public void Test5()
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            foo.TestCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(
                (ex) => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception detected !");
                    Assert.False(true); // This is hit, but doesn't even make the test fail....
                });

            foo.TestCommand.Execute().Subscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

All the tests cause the exception to be thrown, all tests should fail IMO, but only the one *not using* the `ReactiveCommand is failing.

[image: Test results that shows 4 over 5 pass instead of 0 over 5]

Comment: You can use `await` I believe. `IObservable` is awaitable.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad, Thanks but it does not compile. `IObservable<Foo> does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' ...`

Comment: It should... Which version are you running?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I can see `System.Reactive 4.3.2` as dependency of ReactiveUI

Comment: @AluanHaddad I just noticed that `IObservable<T>` is defined in System namespace from the vanilla .NET framework (4.8) . And it does not look 'awaitable', it just inherits from `IDisposable`.

Comment: That's correct actually. `GetAwaiter` is an extension method provided by `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable` class. You are using that namespace so you should have it.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks ok I think got it now : https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/156, apparently `.ToList()`will give an AsyncEnumerable, will try it

Comment: @AluanHaddad `await foo.TestCommand.Execute().ToList();` works fine and solve my issue. Want to create a proper answer out of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries and also the help of this doc : http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html , I finally got the thing that was missing.

One need to :

- use the TestScheduler
- *and tell the test scheduler to run* (which will immediately executes everything in the observable)

So this adaptation from Test3 in the question seem to work fine :

```
[Fact]
public void Test3()
{
    var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var foo = new Foo(testScheduler);
    foo.TestCommand.Execute().Subscribe();
    testScheduler.Start(); // YEAY
}
```

I general, we ended up wrapping all our tests that makes use of `ReactiveCommands` in a `With` block :

```
new TestScheduler().With(scheduler =>
{
    var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var foo = new Foo(testScheduler);
    foo.TestCommand.Execute().Subscribe();
    testScheduler.Start(); // YEAY
});
```

Results in a failed test with the stack trace showing it's caused by the Exception :

```
 Tests.ReactiveCommandTests.Test3
   Source: ReactiveCommandTests.cs line 50
   Duration: 45 ms

  Message: 
    System.Exception : Boom
  Stack Trace: 
    Foo.Explode() line 26
    <>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Create>b__1(IObserver`1 observer) line 108
    CreateWithDisposableObservable`1.SubscribeCore(IObserver`1 observer) line 35
    ObservableBase`1.Subscribe(IObserver`1 observer) line 58
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    <.cctor>b__2_1(Exception ex) line 16
    AnonymousSafeObserver`1.OnError(Exception error) line 62
    ObserveOnObserverNew`1.DrainStep(ConcurrentQueue`1 q) line 553
    ObserveOnObserverNew`1.DrainShortRunning(IScheduler recursiveScheduler) line 509
    <>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<ScheduleAbsolute>b__0(IScheduler scheduler, TState state1) line 430
    ScheduledItem`1.Invoke() line 44
    VirtualTimeSchedulerBase`2.Start() line 174
    ReactiveCommandTests.Test3() line 56
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pac0, try this.  You'll need to add the FluentAssertions package.  I'd recommend defining a custom Exception too.

```
// Arrange
var foo = new Foo();            

// Act
var result = foo.TestCommand.Execute().Subscribe();

// Assert
result.Should().BeOfType<Exception>();
```

Comment: I'll give it a try ! thanks, Yes, the not-custom Exception was just for the sake of the [mcve]. In the meantime, I also found a solution using the schedulers which seems  to give the correct results.

Comment: This package is interesting, but it replaces the problem by another :`System.Reactive.ObserveOnObserverLongRunning` is detected, whatever my method `Explode()` does (throws or returns peacefully), so it does not solve the issue, because the test will always fail even if there is no problem. Thanks anyway!